# insert either pubdate or timestamp into database

Tags: php, mysql

From a rss feed i have either pubdate as well the timestamp:

```
pubdate:
Thu, 03 May 2012 09:00:00 +0000
timestamp:
1336035600
```

However when i insert it into the database it's always: 0000-00-00 ETC.
This is the query:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO adafruit_articles VALUES ('', '$title', '$link', '$comments', '$timestamp', '$description', '$content')";
```

[image]

Is my database set up correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it into a MySQL friendly format. Passing the timestamp to the `date()` function makes this easy:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1336035600);
```

Or use the [DateTime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$date = new DateTime(1336035600);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: do i need to change the 'timestamp' type in phpmyadmin to dateTime or date, or leave it as it is now?

Comment: You don't need to change it. The code above works with a timestamp just fine.